# How to validate properly razor page with asp annotations?

Tags: c#, html, asp.net-core, razor

So I'm trying to validate "Name" field in my modal which is a PartialView but I can't get it to work. I tried changing the places of the PartialView from _PlayersTable to Index but still not working. One thing I noticed is that on my Create action modal, when I put the partial view in _PlayersTable the validation for the modal is not working and if I put it in Index it's working as intended. My question is there any way to render the view as it is like now or should I create more ViewModels for each action and render the views one by one in the Index?

_PlayersTable:

```html
@using BGStats.ViewModels;
@using BGStats.ViewModels.Players
@using PagedList
@model IPagedList<PlayerViewModel>

@if (Model.Any())
{
    <table class="table">
        <tr>
            <th scope="col">Player</th>
            <th scope="col">Name</th>
            <th>
                <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#addPlayer">Create</button>
            </th>
        </tr>
        @foreach (var player in Model)
        {

            <tr>
                <td>@player.Image</td>
                <td>@player.Name</td>
                <td>
                    <button type="button" class="btn btn-warning" data-toggle="modal" data-target="@("#EditPlayer-" + player.Id)" data-url="@Url.Action($"Edit/{player.Id}")"><i class="bi bi-pencil"></i></button>
                </td>
            </tr>
            //Problem is here. Need to be in the index.cshtml
            @await Html.PartialAsync("~/Views/Player/Edit.cshtml", player)
        }
    </table>
}
else
{
    <h2 style="text-align:center">There's no one here yet. :(</h2>
    <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#addPlayer">Create</button>
}
```

Index:

```html
@using BGStats.ViewModels.Players
@model PlayersViewModel
@{
    ViewData["Title"] = "Players";
}

<body>
    <div class="d-flex" id="wrapper">
        <!-- Sidebar-->
        <div class="border-end bg-white" id="sidebar-wrapper">
            <div class="sidebar-heading border-bottom bg-light">
                <a asp-controller="Home" asp-action="Index" style="color:inherit; text-decoration: none">BGStats</a>
            </div>

            <div class="list-group list-group-flush">
                <a asp-controller="Games" asp-action="Index" class="list-group-item list-group-item-action list-group-item-light p-3">Games</a>
            </div>

            <div class="list-group list-group-flush">
                <a asp-controller="Players" asp-action="Index" class="list-group-item list-group-item-action list-group-item-light p-3">Players</a>
            </div>
        </div>
        <!-- Page content wrapper-->
        <div id="page-content-wrapper">
            <!-- Top navigation-->
            <nav class="navbar navbar-expand-lg navbar-light bg-light border-bottom">
                <div class="container-fluid">
                    <button class="btn btn-primary" id="sidebarToggle"><span class="navbar-toggler-icon"></span></button>
                    <button class="navbar-toggler" type="button" data-bs-toggle="collapse" data-bs-target="#navbarSupportedContent" aria-controls="navbarSupportedContent" aria-expanded="false" aria-label="Toggle navigation"><span class="navbar-toggler-icon"></span></button>
                    <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="navbarSupportedContent">
                        <ul class="navbar-nav ms-auto mt-2 mt-lg-0">
                            <li class="nav-item dropdown">
                                <a class="nav-link dropdown-toggle" id="navbarDropdown" role="button" data-bs-toggle="dropdown" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false">Account</a>
                                <div class="dropdown-menu dropdown-menu-end" aria-labelledby="navbarDropdown">
                                    <a class="dropdown-item" asp-area="Identity" asp-page="/Account/Manage/Index">Settings</a>
                                    <div class="dropdown-divider"></div>
                                    <a class="dropdown-item" asp-area="Identity" asp-page="/Account/Logout" asp-route-returnUrl="@Url.Action("Index", "Home", new { area = "" })">Logout</a>
                                </div>
                            </li>
                        </ul>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </nav>
            <!-- Page content-->
            <div class="container-fluid">
                @await Html.PartialAsync("_PlayersTable", Model.Players)
                @await Html.PartialAsync("~/Views/Player/Create.cshtml", new PlayerViewModel())
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</body>
```

Edit:

```html
@using BGStats.ViewModels.Players
@model PlayerViewModel

<div class="modal fade" id="EditPlayer-@Model.Id" aria-labelledby="EditPlayerLabel" aria-hidden="true">
    <div class="modal-dialog">
        <div class="modal-content">
            <div class="modal-header">
                <h5 class="modal-title" id="EditPlayerLabel">Player</h5>
                <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close">
                    <span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span>
                </button>
            </div>
            <div class="modal-body">
                <form asp-controller="Player" asp-action="Edit" method="post">
                    <div asp-validation-summary="ModelOnly" class="text-danger"></div>
                    <div class="form-group">
                        <input type="hidden" asp-for="Id" />
                        <label asp-for="Name" class="control-label"></label>
                        <input asp-for="Name" class="form-control" />
                        <span asp-validation-for="Name" class="text-danger"></span>
                    </div>
                    <div class="modal-footer">
                        <button type="button" class="btn btn-secondary" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
                        <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary">Save</button>
                    </div>
                </form>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

PlayerController:

```html
public async Task<IActionResult> Edit(int id)
        {
            var player = await playerService.GetByIdAsync(id);

            return PartialView("Edit", player);
        }

        [HttpPost]
        public async Task<IActionResult> Edit(PlayerViewModel playerModel)
        {
            if (!ModelState.IsValid)
            {
                return PartialView("Edit", playerModel);
            }

            var player = playerModel.ToDTO();
            await playerService.UpdatePlayerAsync(player);

            return RedirectToAction("Index", "Players");
        }
```

PlayersController:

```html
public async Task<IActionResult> Index(int playerPage = 1)
        {
            var players = await playerService.GetAllAsync();

            var playersToShow = players.Select(m => m.ToViewModel()).ToPagedList(playerPage, 10);

            var resolute = new PlayersViewModel()
            {
                Players = playersToShow
            };

            return View(resolute);
        }
```

Comment: Could you share your javascript code? And what are your models look like ? "when I put the partial view in _PlayersTable the validation for the modal is not working " Try to use `F12` to see if any error messages in the console.

Comment: @Qing Guo ViewModels: https://pastebin.com/JCUxAQqk (don't know how to add code to reply haha). I don't have any JS linked to my views. For the "when I put the partial view in _PlayersTable the validation for the modal is not working" I meant that when I place await Html.PartialAsync("~/Views/Player/Create.cshtml", new PlayerViewModel()) in _PlayersTable the validation is stopping to work for the Create method and I'm wondering how to make await Html.PartialAsync("~/Views/Player/Edit.cshtml", player) which is in the foreach loop to go in Index because that's why the validation is not workin

Comment: Sorry, I am confused that if you don't have JS code how do you show the modal.  And what do you mean "I'm wondering how to make await Html.PartialAsync("~/Views/Player/Edit.cshtml", player) which is in the foreach loop to go in Index " could you explain more?

Comment: For the modal you can check this guy https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=X3Jc5UfGhhE&t=332s&ab_channel=CodingWorld since I saw it from him. What I meant is how to tell Index view to know for which player I'm trying to access the Edit modal form because I don't have second parameter for await Html.PartialAsync("~/Views/Player/Edit.cshtml", player) and if I remove the player parameter since it's invalid in the IIndex view because the player is a variable from the foreach loop, it doesn't even load up the modal.

Comment: Alright, now I found out that the Edit's validation is not working because the partial view is in the foreach loop.